# How to Use "Or" in the merge condition "WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following statement:

```
MERGE dbo.SystemCustomer As TARGET
USING (Select * 
       From dbo.vClients 
       Where ClientNumber Is Not Null) As SOURCE
    On TARGET.CustNumber = SOURCE.ClientNumber
WHEN MATCHED And (TARGET.DisplayCustNumber<>SOURCE.VisualID Or 
                  TARGET.CustName<>ISNULL(SOURCE.CustName,'') 
             And IsNull(SOURCE.VisualID,'') <> '' And IsNull(TARGET.DisplayCustNumber,'') <> ''
THEN Update Set TARGET.DisplayCustNumber = SOURCE.VisualID,
                TARGET.CustName = ISNULL(SOURCE.CustName,'')    
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN Insert (CustNumber, DisplayCustNumber, CustName)
     Values (SOURCE.ClientNumber, SOURCE.VisualID, ISNULL(SOURCE.CustName,''))  
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source --or IsNull(TARGET.DisplayCustNumber,'') = ''
THEN Delete;
```

I'd like to delete records both when not matched by source and when `Target.DisplayCustNumber` is empty or `null` (stated  at the comment after the `"WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source"` statement) - but apparently it's not possible syntax wise.
How do I bypass this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Considered moving that condition to join between target and source?

Comment: I don't think that would give me the desired results for the matched statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really test without your table definitions, but you can keep your `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE` and add another `WHEN MATCHED AND <condition> THEN DELETE`.

```
MERGE dbo.SystemCustomer As TARGET
USING (Select * 
       From dbo.vClients 
       Where ClientNumber Is Not Null) As SOURCE
    On TARGET.CustNumber = SOURCE.ClientNumber
WHEN MATCHED And (TARGET.DisplayCustNumber<>SOURCE.VisualID Or 
                  TARGET.CustName<>ISNULL(SOURCE.CustName,'') 
             And IsNull(SOURCE.VisualID,'') <> '' And IsNull(TARGET.DisplayCustNumber,'') <> ''
THEN Update Set TARGET.DisplayCustNumber = SOURCE.VisualID,
                TARGET.CustName = ISNULL(SOURCE.CustName,'')   

WHEN MATCHED AND IsNull(TARGET.DisplayCustNumber,'') = '' THEN DELETE -- Add this line

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN Insert (CustNumber, DisplayCustNumber, CustName)
     Values (SOURCE.ClientNumber, SOURCE.VisualID, ISNULL(SOURCE.CustName,''))  
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source --or IsNull(TARGET.DisplayCustNumber,'') = ''
THEN Delete;
```

There are a few limitations on multiple `MATCHED` statements, but they are OK for your case (just keep an eye if you edit it further):

> The MERGE statement can have at most two WHEN MATCHED clauses. If two
>   clauses are specified, then the first clause must be accompanied by an
>   AND clause. For any given row, the second WHEN MATCHED clause is only
>   applied if the first is not. If there are two WHEN MATCHED clauses,
>   then one must specify an UPDATE action and one must specify a DELETE
>   action. If UPDATE is specified in the clause, and more than one row of
>   matches a row in target_table based on , SQL Server returns an error.
>   The MERGE statement cannot update the same row more than once, or
>   update and delete the same row.